# Toggling keys / c++

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard

I try to register if a key has been toggled on or off like this:

```
if (pKeyBuffer[VK_TAB] & 0xFF81)
{
   functionA();
}

if (pKeyBuffer[VK_TAB] & 1)
{
   functionB();
}
```

But there is a big problem in the above code - state of the VK_TAB is not known at startup and because of that, sometimes, i have to press Tab one more time at the runtime to set it to the default state.

I cant use regular '0xF0' or '0' because i cant afford having `functionA()` or `functionB()` called multiple times. I need switch-like behavior(i.e. if Tab is pressed, even though it is being held down, 
`functionA()` still executes only once).

So is there any way to get key state info to perform that first keystroke? Or maybe you can suggest some alternative approach? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a situation like this you want to use the [`GetKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, this will get the key press and key toggle info at the time its called for the given key.

so, if you want to check if tab is held down, use `GetKeyState(VK_TAB) & 0x8000`, if you want to check is its toggled use `GetKeyState(VK_TAB) & 1`.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Abdulali: its use is extremely simple, but I added examples anyways (over and above the example in the MSDN link...)

Comment: `GetKeyState()` will not work: `The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue. The status does not reflect the interrupt-level state associated with the hardware. Use the GetAsyncKeyState function to retrieve that information.`  from [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Remarks section.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn: that just means you need to have a message pump to catch the input, so unless the user is doing stuff before the window is created, it doesn't matter

Comment: I got it working like this: `if ((GetKeyState(VK_TAB) & 0x0001)!=0) //do something`

Comment: Yes you are right. You want to know when the key is **toggled**, not it is up or down. So you should use `GetKeyState()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need [`GetAsyncKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293.aspx). Define a function:

```
bool IsKeyDown( int vk )
{
    return (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_TAB) & 0x8000) != 0;
}
```

And use like this:

```
if( IsKeyDown(VK_TAB) )
{
    // The key is currently down
}
else
{
    // The key is currently up
}
```

If you want to precisely catch changes in key states, you need to use [Windows Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589.aspx).